# ATmega48PB: wdt in interrupt mode still reset the MCU

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, watchdog

I read the datasheet and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/197737/122430) question, but there's still something wrong here.
Here my wdt init code:

```
cli();
MCUSR &= ~_BV(WDRF);
WDTCSR |= _BV(WDCE) | _BV(WDE);
WDTCSR = _BV(WDP2) | _BV(WDP1) | _BV(WDP0);
WDTCSR |= _BV(WDIF);
WDTCSR |= _BV(WDIE);
```

Leaving fire the wdt I expect it does nothing but set the `WDIF` bit, instead it resets the MCU.
Is there something wrong in my approach?

Comment: Do you have an interrupt handler? (or do you leave interrupts off?)

Comment: @user253751, I don't have and I don't want an ISR (for this reason I don't enable the interrupts with `sei()`). I'm going to check the `WDIF` manually.

Comment: A watchdog blocked by SEI() wouldn't be much of a watchdog since it could be disabled by a trivial software bug or glitch.  Typically resetting the processor is *exactly* what they do.

Comment: How is the WDTON fuse bit programmed? There is also no watchdog reset before configuring it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I know how to use a wdt "usually" :) this is a bootloader and I *need* to use the interrupt mode - as provided by this MCU

Comment: @Justme, it is programmed, otherwise no reset will occur at all.

Comment: And by "programmed" you mean set to "0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because WDTON fuse bit is programmed, or '0', the WDE and WDIE bits are ignored and the only time out action from the watchdog is a system reset. Setting the WDTON fuse bit to unprogrammed, or '1', will enable the WDE and WDIE bit usage and thus interrupt action on time-out can be selected.

Comment: Right. Even after 15+ years of AVR programming, I still get confused by the 0|1 meaning of the fuses...

Comment: It's OK. I do have to confess that I have not touched AVRs for about 12 years now, so my AVR skills are not up to date either.

Answer (score 1):

If you *program* the WDTON fuse (ie, set it to the non-default value of 0), then according to the data sheet you are locked into System Reset rather than Interrupt mode; this would not appear to be what you want.

It would appear that what you do want is a combination of Interrupt and System Reset mode, where the first count expiration sets WDIF and triggers and interrupt, and the second causes a reset.

However, if you do that *without* an ISR, you're going to need to be sure to keep re-setting the WDIE bit after it is cleared on each counter expiration, as if the count expires when WDIE is *already* unset, a reset will occur.